# How to scrollview in List View in Android

Tags: java, android

I added 11 to 12 column in List view, but I am not able to see all columns. While I scroll list_view will be able to see all columns. Can someone give me ideas how to do this? Here is my XML file code:

ListView Item Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_Email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4_Mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5_Products"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6_Budget"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7Priority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8_Status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9_Notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10_Date_Reminder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11_Time_Reminder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12_AddToContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And here is my ListView Code xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_DisplayData"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `ListView` into a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and put all your content in there.

Or you create your own ListViewAdapter (or take an existing one such as the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)) and let the adapter insert your data into your listview.

For the latter option, your Activity needs to extend ListActivity and your listview should have the id `android.R.id.list`.